# How to upload XML to MySQL in react with axios and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, axios

I am trying to upload a XML file to MySQl server.
I have a React web app, I am using Axios and NodeJS.

I was using the follwing statement to import the xml file to the product table directly from the workbench

`LOAD XML INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/products.xml" INTO TABLE product ROWS IDENTIFIED BY <Product>`;

It worked fine.

Now I want to have a button that will upload anew xml file and replace the existing data in the table.

What I tried so far is using the HTML input file element, grabing the file from the `event.target.files[0]` and sending the file object to the server with a POST request.

I am not realy sure how to go from here I cant find a statement that can import the data out of the file object and imoprt it into the sql table.

any ideas? what is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, my site was deployed to Heroku.
Apparently the clearDB, Heroku's add-on sql database, does not allow the use of LOAD XML INFILE / LOAD DATA INFILE as said here -  https://getsatisfaction.com/cleardb/topics/load-data-local-infile.

What I ended up doing was converting the xml file to JS object.
That solution presented a new problem, my xml file was around 3MB summed up to over 12000 rows to insert to the database.
MySQL does not allow inserting more then a 1000 rows in a single query.
I had to split the object to several chuncks and loop through them uploading each one by it self.
This process takes some time to execute and I am sure there are better ways of doing it.

If anyone can shed some light on how best to go about it or provide an alternative I would apprreciate it.